# Cannot Connect to the Wifi that configured with (IEEE) 802.1x protocol

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, wifi, networkmanager, 802.1x

In Ubuntu 22.04 I can easily connect to 802.1x wifi with following configurations succesfully;

```
Security -> WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication -> Protected EAP (PEAP)
NO CA certificate required
PEAP version -> Automatic
Inner Authentication -> MSCHAPv2
Username -> domain user
Password -> domain password
```

Unfortunately, I cannot connect with same configurations on RHEL 9.x version. It always requests authentication.

I am checking NetworkManager systemd logs by `journalctl -u NetworkManager` which you find below.

```
Aug 02 15:28:53 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979333.2656] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:28:53 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979333.2658] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:28:53 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979333.2756] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:28:53 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979333.2756] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:33:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979636.1017] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 5E:A3:07:65:3B:6C (scanning)
Aug 02 15:33:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979636.1177] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:33:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979636.1177] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:33:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979636.1306] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:33:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979636.1306] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:38:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979936.0978] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to CA:78:8C:A3:2F:EC (scanning)
Aug 02 15:38:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979936.1134] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:38:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979936.1134] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:38:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979936.1195] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:38:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690979936.1196] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:43:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980236.1027] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 6E:26:4A:C6:0B:FC (scanning)
Aug 02 15:43:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980236.1184] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:43:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980236.1184] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:43:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980236.1255] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:43:56 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980236.1255] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.3780] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="bd1bf1cc-030c-4659-9f12-f4a2c4122140" name="SSID" args="802-1x.password,802-1x.identity" pid=7970 uid=1249410144 result="success"
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.3810] policy: auto-activating connection 'SSID' (bd1bf1cc-030c-4659-9f12-f4a2c4122140)
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.3815] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'SSID' (bd1bf1cc-030c-4659-9f12-f4a2c4122140)
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.3815] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4048] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to E0:06:E6:0A:DB:89 (preserve)
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4207] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4210] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SSID' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4210] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4215] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4215] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4223] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4226] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4229] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SSID' has security, and secrets exist. No new secrets needed.
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4229] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SSID'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4229] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'password' value ''
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4230] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4231] Config: added 'identity' value 'nnoenese@corp.innovile.com'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4231] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4348] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4348] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4437] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:45:23 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980323.4437] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.4673] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.4673] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.4867] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.4867] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.5132] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:45:24 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980324.5133] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:45:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980326.6375] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:45:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980326.6375] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:45:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980326.7400] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:45:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980326.7401] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:45:48 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980348.2156] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Aug 02 15:45:48 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980348.2158] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:45:48 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980348.2162] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Aug 02 15:46:02 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980362.7421] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 02 15:46:02 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980362.7421] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.1621] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.1630] device (wlp2s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.1630] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="bd1bf1cc-030c-4659-9f12-f4a2c4122140" name="SSID" pid=7970 uid=1249410144 result="success"
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.1759] device (wlp2s0): Deactivation failed: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.1759] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2078] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to EA:74:05:C6:E5:C8 (scanning)
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2243] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'SSID' (bd1bf1cc-030c-4659-9f12-f4a2c4122140)
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2247] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2248] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2250] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2477] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to E0:06:E6:0A:DB:89 (preserve)
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2635] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2637] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SSID' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2638] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2652] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2655] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2657] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SSID' has security, and secrets exist. No new secrets needed.
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SSID'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'password' value ''
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2658] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2659] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2659] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2659] Config: added 'identity' value 'nnoenese@corp.innovile.com'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2659] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2808] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:46:25 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980385.2809] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:46:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980386.2891] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:46:26 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980386.2892] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3076] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3076] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3710] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3711] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3989] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:46:27 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980387.3990] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:46:29 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980389.5244] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:46:29 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980389.5244] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:46:29 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980389.6269] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:46:29 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980389.6269] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:46:50 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980410.2160] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Aug 02 15:46:50 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980410.2161] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:46:50 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980410.2165] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Aug 02 15:47:02 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980422.6306] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 02 15:47:02 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980422.6306] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4027] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4032] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4034] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SSID' has security, and secrets exist. No new secrets needed.
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4035] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SSID'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4035] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4035] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4035] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4035] Config: added 'password' value ''
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4036] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4036] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4036] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4036] Config: added 'identity' value 'nnoenese@corp.innovile.com'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4036] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4162] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:47:13 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980433.4163] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4393] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4393] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4431] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4431] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4720] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:47:14 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980434.4721] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 02 15:47:16 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980436.5984] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:47:16 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980436.5984] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Aug 02 15:47:16 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980436.7008] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:47:16 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980436.7009] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 02 15:47:38 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980458.2157] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Aug 02 15:47:38 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980458.2159] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:47:38 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980458.2164] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.5911] device (wlp2s0): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.5911] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6188] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to DE:C5:8C:07:C1:52 (scanning)
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6345] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'SSID'
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6346] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6346] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6348] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6455] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:47:39 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980459.6456] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:52:41 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980761.1029] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 82:37:7B:69:F5:8B (scanning)
Aug 02 15:52:41 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980761.1190] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:52:41 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980761.1190] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> interface_disabled
Aug 02 15:52:41 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980761.1307] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 02 15:52:41 nno-lp-mab-ub NetworkManager[1225]: [1690980761.1307] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
```